# Do SQL Server temp tables live in memory even after the script finishes executing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

If I have a stored procedure that users are running constantly that creates temp tables and **don't** clear these temp tables at the end of the stored procedure, do these temp tables continue to exist and use up memory after the execution of the SP?

I tagged SQL Server 2008 because this is the one we are currently using and 2019 is the version we are upgrading to soon. I'm wondering if this question has a different answer in these two versions.

Comment: Yes, and no... In recent versions of SQL Server the temporary tables can actually be persisted for performance reasons (there's a list of caveats on when this happens), but they don't contain any data. As for memory, that is a *completely* different matter; SQL Server doesn't release memory to the OS after it's used it, but that doesn't mean that the temporary table remains in that memory. A temporary table (from the perspective of being accessible) only persists for as long as the scope that created it does; for an SP that's when the procedure's execution ends.

Comment: Note that whether or not user "clear" the temp table (deleting, truncating or dropping), when the session ends, the temp table goes poof. If *creating* the table was done in the stored procedure, then it goes poof at the end of the sproc, whether or not it's explicitly dropped.

Comment: We've used the same technique as you through sql 2000 => 2019 and i doubt it has changed since, you dont' need to drop temp tables in any normal usage

Comment: In reference to my comment: [SQL Server Temporary Object Caching](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching)

Comment: I made it a habit to drop temp tables at the beginning and at the end of all of my SPs for the past 4 years...what a waste of time lol

Comment: Yes, `DROP`ing them at the start or end is effectively pointless, @whatin1992 . Note, however, that if a temporary object of the same name is created  before the execution of the procedure, that will cause problems. As such it's a good habit to give your temporary objects a meaningful name, that (hopefully) won't result in a clash. Something like `#temp` would be a *poor* choice, for example. Note in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qK0sAs8n) that in the batch where I `EXEC` twice, only 1 row in each dataset is returned, not 2 in the latter, and the whole thing fails ihe former batch.

Comment: If you end up running the stored proc code outside the context of the stored proc whilst developing/debugging then having the `DROP` statements can be useful though.

Comment: It doesn't do any harm to drop the temp table at the end of a proc, or drop if exists (it is, or at least *was* the recommended practice), however just be aware what goes on behind the scenes is not the same as dropping a normal user table as per the caching of meta data described above.

Comment: @Larnu about your note - does that apply to 2 different sessions creating a temp table with the same name? Let's say in Report A and Report B I use a SP that creates `#temp` with wildly different schemas. If two different users were to each run one of these reports, could there be a conflict because of the same temp table name? Or is SQL Server smart enough to apply some level of scoping to prevent this?

Comment: Temporary tables are still scoped to the scope they are in @whatin1992 . 2 connections can both create a temporary table with the same name; they are different scopes.

Comment: @Larnu phew! That's a relief. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: One caveat to be aware of is that while temporary tables themselves aren't accessible beyond the scope that created them SQL Server will use a deferred drop if their data is less than around 8MB - this can catch you out due to the table's statistics still being cached. If you regularly recreate that same temporary tables that include indexes and/or unique constraints and/or primary key constraints you should execute `UPDATE STATISTICS` against them after populating them otherwise the statistics cached from previous use can mislead query planner in subsequent queries within the current scope.